# sql LIKE with certain restirctions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comma delimeted values as a string within a `varchar` field. I am trying to carry out a sume based on `like` but am getting undesired results.

`SELECT SUM(PostLiked LIKE '%1%') as PostLikedSum FROM myTable WHERE GroupId = 12`

```
PostLiked      |     GroupId 
_____________________________
1,13,47,87,1   |        12

12,3           |        12
```

My query is returning a `sum` of 2 because it is matching `12`. Is there a way of limiting this so it matches the value `1` within the field?

Comment: `SUM(PostLiked LIKE '%1%')` is it valid?? I i'm not sure.

Comment: you can use here `IN` for searching `PostLinked`.

Comment: which result you expecting .?

Comment: If you absolutely have to store comma-separated values in a column (and it's advised to properly normalize your data instead), then use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) rather than LIKE or Regexp.... it was written specialy by the developers of MySQL for just this case, though no solution will be as efficient as proper normalization of your data

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm expecting sum `1` as i'd like it to match the first row only

Comment: @MarkBaker won't this also find matches for `12` when searching for `1`? http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php This example searched for `william` and returns `william norton, william smith`

Comment: @steve - No it won't..... it looks for an exact match between the commas, as explained the the documentation that I linked; and I don't see ___any___ examples that searches for `william` in the MySQL documentation... the example in the documentation that I linked is `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');` The example from W3schools is using a rather different check, with substrings.... when using docs, use official docs as a first option

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(PostLiked) as PostLikedSum FROM myTable WHERE GroupId = 12 AND FIND_IN_SET(1, PostLiked) > 0`

Comment: In the w3schools example, the set is `'William,steven,jung,angalo'`, and the substring check means that it is searching for `'William'` in that set

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker I went with `SUM(FIND_IN_SET('1',PostLikedSum ) > 0 ) AS PostLikedSum` as i have multiple sums in a query. If you post this as an asnwer i'll accept it to help others.

Comment: To help other you have to quit that awful practice of storing comma-delimited values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this problem is to properly normalize your data, as this will always be easier to manage and more efficient for performance; but if you do have to work with comma-separated values in a data column, then the developers of MySQL wrote a function called [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) especially for this situation.

```
SELECT COUNT(PostLiked) as PostLikedSum
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE GroupId = 12
  AND FIND_IN_SET(1, PostLiked) > 0
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(FIND_IN_SET(1, PostLiked ) > 0 ) AS PostLikedSum
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE GroupId = 12
```

Will select only those entries with `1` in the comma-separated `PostLiked` set; and because it was designed specifically for this purpose, it is generally far more efficient than using LIKE or REGEX to check the value.
But none of these options can use indexes, so they'll never be as efficient as normalized data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT` instead of `OR's` :

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CONCAT(',',t.PostLiked,',') LIKE '%,1,%' THEN 1 end) as PostLiked
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.GroupId = 12
```

This way the string of `PostLiked` will be constructed as:

```
,1,13,47,87,1,
,12,3,
```

Then you won't have this problem.

Comment: This looked like it could work - just tried it and get an error? `1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT SUM(PostLiked LIKE '%1,%') as PostLikedSum FROM myTable WHERE GroupId = 12
```

Take comma into consideration as this would make the like unique as no other number with a 12,11 or 91 would be considered as there would be some thing else present. Its a kind of a hack but should do the trick

Comment: What about the last `1` ?

Comment: You can add OR statement and check for LIKE '1' . So if only one single character exists and if that's one.

Comment: No, you can't , I asked what if the string is :`2,4,6,1` . Also, do not use `LIKE` for exact match, a single `=` operator is enough.

Comment: Ok then you need regex in sql query and it will do a trick. Regex is your friend, it can take any pattern into consideration. let me write one for you

Comment: Its not for me, and I know what Regex is for. I just corrected you.